# 1d array and insert to make arraylist by index

Tags: php, arrays

hello anyone can help me 
i have one input from main class example like city 
Jakarta , Surabaya , Medan , Bali save in variable 
example first array the values Jakarta . and list Jakarta,Surabaya,Medan and bali 
and next array like Surabaya and list Jakarta, Surabaya , Medan , Bali

from this i hope make a distance inter city and make a array 2 multidimensional
can you give me any ideas ?

mainclass.php

```
    $test = 'Jakarta';
    $test1 = 'Brebes';
    $test2='Pekalongan';
    $test3 ='Semarang';

    $simpankota = array($test,$test1,$test2,$test3);
    $totalkota=array($simpankota);
    $jarakd2->probabilitasTotal ($totalkota);
```

function like

```
   public function probabilitasTotal($totalkota)
   {
      echo "<pre>" . print_r ($totalkota,true) ."</pre>";
      if ($totalkota != null)
      {
         foreach($totalkota as $key => $value)
            {
               foreach($value as $k => $v)
               {
                   $a=array($v);
                  echo "<pre>" .print_r($a ,true)."</pre>";
               }

            }
            $save[] = array_values($totalkota,array_values($a));
            $koplo[]= array($totalkota ,array_values($a));

                  echo "<pre>" .print_r($koplo ,true)."</pre>";
      }

   }
```

but i seen like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jakarta
        [1] => Brebes
        [2] => Pekalongan
        [3] => Semarang
    )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Jakarta
)
Array
(
    [0] => Brebes
)
Array
(
    [0] => Pekalongan
)
Array
(
    [0] => Semarang
)
```

and from there i want make one input and generate to auto make a list from   input

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Jakarta
              (
                  [0] => Jakarta
                  [1] => Brebes
                  [2] => Pekalongan
                  [3] => Semarang
              )

        [1] => Brebes
             (
                  [0] => Jakarta
                  [1] => Brebes
                  [2] => Pekalongan
                  [3] => Semarang
              )
        [2] => Pekalongan
               (
                  [0] => Jakarta
                  [1] => Brebes
                  [2] => Pekalongan
                  [3] => Semarang
              )
        [3] => Semarang
               (
                  [0] => Jakarta
                  [1] => Brebes
                  [2] => Pekalongan
                  [3] => Semarang
              )
    )

)
```

so if i access distance city Semarang - Brebes i only like $cityindex[3][1]

last sorry for bad english :)

Comment: I don't quite get your target structure: where the cities are, should be "Array", if its intended to resemble print_r() output.

Comment: Also, why do you hook up the structure at the zero index of another array?

Comment: @syck because i feel good condition to searching , example if i access city start point : jakarta - Destination : Semarang 
so only i acces like $cityindex[0][3]

Comment: But wouldnt it be better to use `$cityindex['Semerang']['Brebes']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public function probabilitasTotal($totalkota) {
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($totalkota, true) . "</pre>";
        if ($totalkota != null) {
            foreach ($totalkota as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                    $koplo[$v] = $value;
                }
            }

            print_r($koplo, true);
        }
    }
```

You wont get what's expected by you as `Brebes` cannot be a `Array` name. It will spelled as `Array` only.

Comment: thankyou its worked from your answer.. thank you very much !

Comment: I'm glad, You can accept it as an answer and upvote it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will suffice, but I made this from your example...

```
$test  = 'Jakarta';
$test1 = 'Brebes';
$test2 = 'Pekalongan';
$test3 = 'Semarang';

$simpankota = array($test,$test1,$test2,$test3);

probabilitasTotal($simpankota);

function probabilitasTotal($simpankota) {
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($simpankota, true) . "</pre>";
    $simpankota2 = $simpankota;
    $a = array();
    foreach ($simpankota as $key => $value) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($simpankota2 as $k => $v) {
            $array[] = $value . ' - ' . $v;
        }
        $a[$key] = $array;
    }
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($a, true) . "</pre>";
}
```

It outputs the follwing...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Jakarta
    [1] => Brebes
    [2] => Pekalongan
    [3] => Semarang
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jakarta - Jakarta
            [1] => Jakarta - Brebes
            [2] => Jakarta - Pekalongan
            [3] => Jakarta - Semarang
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brebes - Jakarta
            [1] => Brebes - Brebes
            [2] => Brebes - Pekalongan
            [3] => Brebes - Semarang
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pekalongan - Jakarta
            [1] => Pekalongan - Brebes
            [2] => Pekalongan - Pekalongan
            [3] => Pekalongan - Semarang
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Semarang - Jakarta
            [1] => Semarang - Brebes
            [2] => Semarang - Pekalongan
            [3] => Semarang - Semarang
        )

)
```

Comment: Instead of the inner loop, you can simply add `$simpankota` to the array.

Comment: @syck I tried that initially - but i couldn't see a way to use the outside-loop-value

Comment: @MaggsWeb thankyou very much .. will worked ! 
thankyouuu !! :)

Comment: @MaggsWeb You are correct. Sorry, I was distracted by OP's weird target data structure. =)

Comment: @MaggsWeb , hello can i have some question again?
can i get distance city in inter- city on value in arraylist>